# Use multiprocessing to parallelize agent code in simulation

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, agent

I have written code that simulates physalum in python, based off [Sebastien Lagues video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-iSQQgOd1A&t=934s) from 14:08, I got the code working however it is single threaded, and gets very slow with many agents.
I have tried using Threading, and concurrent.futures, both of which slowed it down compared to only using it single threaded. I would like to parallelize this, but I feel I'm out of my depth. I have a feeling I will need multiprocessing using background processes that stay running and get given data to process and stick it in a queue for using.

The agents are all stored in a list called agents, and can be iterated through using:
for agent in agents:
and to update a given agent:
agent = agent_update(agent, pixels)

pixels is also important and is required to update the pixels properly, it will be updated after every agent has updated.
To play around with the [code](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0b12NR1caeE3rGCa6xSBRASGQ#slime2)

Comment: Python multithreading is *very* tricky due to the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://realpython.com/python-gil/). Essentially, that means that only one thread can run at a time but multiple threads can block each other. There's ongoing work to remove the GIL with [some improvements coming in 3.12 and 3.13](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3694512/python-312-faster-leaner-more-future-proof.html)

Comment: Yes, so I've heard, that's why I believe multiprocessing is the answer

Comment: It's a very heavy workaround. Cross-process communication is the heaviest way of communication. There are alternatives, like libraries that execute multithreading code in C or Rust. Polars for example is a lot faster than Pandas precisely because it takes advantage of Rust. If your code performs I/O, using asynchronous IO is *better* than multiprocessing because it doesn't block a core waiting for the OS to complete an IO operation

Comment: unfortunately python is all I know, so I might have to learn C just so I can do shaders and GPU work

Comment: Python is clearly not suited for such a computationally intensive program. The standard default implementation is an interpreter and (so) it is very slow. The standard/common way to make it fast is to use vectorized functions (i.e. C function doing most of the computational work, as opposed to interpreted functions) like with Numpy. The thing is this require many deep modification of your code and this will not be simple to use either. There are other issues: the PIL and PyGame are slow as well as `uniform_filter` of Scipy... Most Python modules are unfortunately not very fast.

Comment: Here, the best solution in Python is to try to use Cython/Numba but you will not be able to reach much more than 1-2 FPS with them (I tried). Moving to C/C++/Rust will definitively help to improve performance. Shaders are a rather good idea for this computation but I do not advise to try to use them directly. GPUs are more complex then CPU to use (especially for beginners, as there are a lot of things to learn). A quite-naive parallel code in C should be able to reach >10 FPS. For more, the C code needs to be optimized carefully (e.g. SIMD-friendly optimization like on GPUs).

Comment: that's a shame, I am planning on getting on to c++, and in the original video that's how he implemented it, I was thinking in the future I could use CUDA, however that's another rabbit hole, I used chatGPT to even help me to make one for an older version of the current program but I didn't understand it so couldn't get further